# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at proj5.main(proj5.java:15)

Tags: java

I am getting this error when I compile my program.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at proj5.main(proj5.java:15)

When I double click on the error it directs me to "String origin = args[0];"

Here is the whole code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class proj5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //validates command line
        if(args == null || args.length != 6){
            System.out.println("Invalid command line arguments");
            System.out.println("Usage: Project5 [origin] [minSpeed] [maxSpeed] [maxBoxcars] [inputFile] [outputFile]");
        }

        //gets arguments        
        String origin = args[0];
        int minSpeed = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int maxSpeed = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        int maxBoxcars = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        String inputFile = args[4];
        String logFile = args[5];

        //create new train log
        TLog log = new TLog(logFile);
        try {
            log.createFile();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Failed to create output file");
        }

        //create train
        Train train = new Train(origin, minSpeed, maxSpeed, maxBoxcars, log);
        //read file
        readFile(inputFile, train);
    }

    private static void readFile(String inputFile, Train train){
        boolean quit = false;

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try { 
            String line;

            //reader for file
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            //loop until end of file or quit
            while (!quit && ((line = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                //get commands
                if(line.equals("PRINT")){
                    //PRINT
                    train.logCommand("PRINT", new String[]{});
                    train.printStatus();                    
                } else if(line.equals("ARRIVE")){//ARRIVE
                    train.logCommand("ARRIVE", new String[]{});
                    train.setArrived();
                } else if(line.equals("DEPART")){//DEPART
                    String city = br.readLine();
                    train.logCommand("DEPART", new String[]{city});

                    train.setDeparted(city);
                }else if(line.equals("SPEEDUP")){//SPEEDUP
                    int mph = Integer.parseInt( br.readLine());
                    train.logCommand("SPEEDUP", new String[]{String.valueOf(mph)});
                    train.speedUp(mph);
                }else if(line.equals("SLOWDOWN")){//SLOWDOWN
                    int mph = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    train.logCommand("SLOWDOWN", new String[]{String.valueOf(mph)});
                    train.slowDown(mph);
                }else if(line.equals("ADDCAR")){//ADDCAR
                    String type = br.readLine();
                    int maxElements = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    BoxCar boxCar = null;
                    //Create new boxcar based on type
                    if(type.equals("PERSON")){
                        boxCar = new PersonCar(maxElements);
                    }else if(type.equals("CARGO")){
                        boxCar = new Car(maxElements);
                    }

                    train.logCommand("ADDCAR", new String[]{type, String.valueOf(maxElements)});
                    train.addCar(boxCar);

                }else if(line.equals("REMOVECAR")){ //REMOVECAR
                    int carNum = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    train.logCommand("REMOVECAR", new String[]{String.valueOf(carNum)});
                    train.removeCar(carNum);                    
                }else if(line.equals("LOAD")){//LOAD
                    String cargoType = br.readLine();
                    int boxCarId = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    String id = br.readLine();

                    CarContents carContents = null;
                    //create contents based upon cargo type
                    if(cargoType.equals("PERSON")){
                        String name =  br.readLine();
                        int age = Integer.parseInt( br.readLine());                 
                        carContents = new Person(id, name, age);                            
                        train.logCommand("LOAD", new String[]{String.valueOf(boxCarId), id, name, String.valueOf(age)});
                    } else if(cargoType.equals("CARGO")){
                        int weight = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                        int height = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                        int width = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                        int length = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());                       
                        carContents = new Cargo(id, weight, height, width, length);
                        train.logCommand("LOAD", new String[]{String.valueOf(boxCarId), String.valueOf(weight), String.valueOf(height),
                                 String.valueOf(width), String.valueOf(length)});
                    }

                    train.load(boxCarId, carContents);

                }else if(line.equals("UNLOAD")){//UNLOAD
                    int boxCarId = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    String cargoId = br.readLine();
                    train.logCommand("UNLOAD", new String[]{String.valueOf(boxCarId), cargoId});
                    train.unload(boxCarId, cargoId);

                }else if(line.equals("QUIT")){//QUIT

                    train.logCommand("QUIT", new String[]{});
                    train.logMessage("Quitting...");
                    quit = true;
                }           
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need the other classes, I have BoxCar.java, Car.java, CarContents.java, CarException.java, Cargo.java, Person.java, PersonCar.java, TLog.java, and Train.java.

This is the only error I am getting and it is preventing me to compile and run the program.

Comment: How are you running your application? `args` can never be `null` when the method is called from the JVM.

Comment: "preventing me to compile" how is this possible since the error is a *runtime* exception?

Answer (score 4):

If the error is at line:

```
String origin = args[0];
```

then it means you are not providing any runtime arguments to your program.

Although you have a check for arguments but you are not taking any corrective action and simply continuing the execution after the `if` block. You may want to move your rest of the code in `else` block to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`:

```
        //validates command line
        if(args == null || args.length != 6){
            System.out.println("Invalid command line arguments");
            System.out.println("Usage: Project5 [origin] [minSpeed] [maxSpeed] [maxBoxcars]           [inputFile] [outputFile]");
        } else {
           //rest of the code
        }
```

Comment: +1 for noticing the lack of else, though I'd simply throw an exception and be done with it.

Comment: Or you can add a return statement at the end of the if-condition: 
        if(args == null || args.length != 6){...
            return;
        }

Comment: I tried putting the rest of the code in else block to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException but it did not work .. any other ideas?

Comment: And, adding a return did not help either!

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be not passing any arguments, so how could access postion 0 of args?